# Why does increment using ++ work with strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, increment, unary-operator

Normally when I get the value of a form input with jQuery I am obliged to convert it to a number before performing any mathematical operations. For instance, using the unary plus operator to convert, and then increment:

```
var x = +$(this).val();
x += 1;
```

But for some reason `++` works with strings and does the conversion automatically:

```
var x = $(this).val();
x++;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m4nka9d3/

Why?  Is this always safe?

Comment: One of the most interesting questions I've seen in weeks. And which, like most really good questions, taught me something in the process of answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works that way because the first thing either of the increment operators does is coerce its operand to a number, this is in [§11.3.1 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3.1). And being in the spec, yes, it's something you can rely on.

Skipping some spectalk, the algorithm is:

- Let `oldValue` be `ToNumber(GetValue(lhs))`.
- Let `newValue` be the result of adding the value `1` to `oldValue`, using the same rules as for the `+` operator (see 11.6.3).
- Call `PutValue(lhs, newValue)`.
- Return `oldValue`.

Whereas, `+=` is defined [quite differently](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.2), **not** coercing to number as an early step, and thus ending up applying string concatenation rather than addition.

Comment: Thanks.. I was always under the impression that `x++` and `x += 1` were the same but apparently this is an important difference.

Comment: @billynoah: That's a very, very good observation. In most languages with B-like syntax (C, Java, etc.), `++x` being essentially `x += 1` (not `x++`, the final value of the expression is different) would be an accurate statement. But not JavaScript, with its loose typing. :-)